# UISlider change width of lines drawn on a view?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am currently working on a drawing application in swift. So far I have implemented buttons that will change the colour of the drawings. I now have a UISlider and want to change the width of the drawings being made. Does anyone know
how this could be implemented, as in what code can I use for the IBAction function in the view controller?

Comment: Can you give some more information on how you are drawing so we can help you

Comment: if you can provide some information on how you are going to make the drawing, increasing the width of which element, may be this will help you:https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView , it's in Obj-c but you can take ref

Answer (score 1):

You can use Value changed event.
Inside value changed event you can get the slider.value assign this value to the width factor.

```
-(IBAction)SliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
UISlider * slider = (UISlider*)sender;
self.drawingWidth = slider.value;
//redraw with the new value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overrided  `touchesBegan` `drawLineFrom` `touchesMoved` methods of the drawing view.

I came accross a well explained example for you. It explains how to control coloring, opacity and brush sizes as well.

Have a lok at this [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift)